# caret chooses non-optimal RMSE?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, regularization, caret, rms

I run a linear regression via caret / glmnet method with "RMSE" as metric. In the final model, caret tells me which values of the tuning parameters alpha and lambda were selected to minimize RMSE.
If I look at the RMSE value corresponding to these selected tuning parameter, however, it seems that this RMSE is not the optimal (i.e. the lowest) value! What am I missing here?

```
load("regression.RData")
data <- cbind(x, y,
              colnames = T)

glmGrid <- expand.grid(.alpha = seq(0, 1, .2),
                       .lambda = 10^seq(1, -2, by = -.2))

control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",
                        number=10,
                        repeats = 3,
                        verboseIter = TRUE,
                        savePredictions = TRUE,
                        allowParallel = TRUE)

fit_glm <- train(x = data[,1:20],
                 y = data[,21],
                 method = "glmnet",
                 family = "gaussian",
                 metric = "RMSE",
                 tuneGrid = glmGrid,
                 trControl = control)
fit_glm
```

Output:

```
fit_glm
glmnet 

100 samples
 20 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 3 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 90, 92, 90, 90, 91, 89, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  alpha  lambda       RMSE      Rsquared   MAE      
  0.0     0.01000000  1.055334  0.8719668  0.8523026
  0.0     0.01584893  1.055334  0.8719668  0.8523026
  0.0     0.02511886  1.055334  0.8719668  0.8523026
  0.0     0.03981072  1.055334  0.8719668  0.8523026
  0.0     0.06309573  1.055334  0.8719668  0.8523026
  0.0     0.10000000  1.055334  0.8719668  0.8523026
  0.0     0.15848932  1.055408  0.8719662  0.8522290
  0.0     0.25118864  1.065504  0.8717957  0.8551781
  0.0     0.39810717  1.092449  0.8712317  0.8765235
  0.0     0.63095734  1.149971  0.8698575  0.9320985
  0.0     1.00000000  1.253825  0.8670977  1.0234817
  0.0     1.58489319  1.413174  0.8623775  1.1587575
  0.0     2.51188643  1.622525  0.8554718  1.3521536
  0.0     3.98107171  1.860948  0.8468095  1.5646762
  0.0     6.30957344  2.099843  0.8374108  1.7731924
  0.0    10.00000000  2.313906  0.8284578  1.9586193
  0.2     0.01000000  1.051300  0.8723212  0.8613115
  0.2     0.01584893  1.050040  0.8725045  0.8598205
  0.2     0.02511886  1.047405  0.8729265  0.8568540
  0.2     0.03981072  1.043798  0.8735702  0.8534024
  0.2     0.06309573  1.039658  0.8744667  0.8489644
  0.2     0.10000000  1.035322  0.8758844  0.8425405
  0.2     0.15848932  1.033494  0.8780124  0.8380310
  0.2     0.25118864  1.038850  0.8816507  0.8445640
  0.2     0.39810717  1.071187  0.8853995  0.8782913
  0.2     0.63095734  1.172810  0.8849036  0.9610087
  0.2     1.00000000  1.363051  0.8808708  1.1149853
  0.2     1.58489319  1.655205  0.8683963  1.3631443
  0.2     2.51188643  2.041614  0.8327090  1.6962855
  0.2     3.98107171  2.475323  0.7251378  2.0814078
  0.2     6.30957344  2.793401  0.5588960  2.3622822
  0.2    10.00000000  2.900915        NaN  2.4555678
  0.4     0.01000000  1.049431  0.8726648  0.8598184
  0.4     0.01584893  1.046385  0.8731813  0.8567977
  0.4     0.02511886  1.042208  0.8739168  0.8533024
  0.4     0.03981072  1.036839  0.8749646  0.8483878
  0.4     0.06309573  1.029555  0.8767482  0.8406084
  0.4     0.10000000  1.022905  0.8792733  0.8326626
  0.4     0.15848932  1.017007  0.8838572  0.8291778
  0.4     0.25118864  1.041423  0.8864255  0.8587007
  0.4     0.39810717  1.131306  0.8841843  0.9305731
  0.4     0.63095734  1.306613  0.8770485  1.0696078
  0.4     1.00000000  1.609777  0.8541953  1.3198522
  0.4     1.58489319  2.049819  0.7873540  1.6980659
  0.4     2.51188643  2.542028  0.6111359  2.1366800
  0.4     3.98107171  2.889678  0.3398729  2.4459795
  0.4     6.30957344  2.900915        NaN  2.4555678
  0.4    10.00000000  2.900915        NaN  2.4555678
  0.6     0.01000000  1.047127  0.8730877  0.8578717
  0.6     0.01584893  1.043099  0.8737899  0.8545034
  0.6     0.02511886  1.037672  0.8747826  0.8498465
  0.6     0.03981072  1.030079  0.8764263  0.8428246
  0.6     0.06309573  1.021369  0.8788328  0.8335780
  0.6     0.10000000  1.010180  0.8831523  0.8235013
  0.6     0.15848932  1.017553  0.8865013  0.8382186
  0.6     0.25118864  1.080487  0.8847023  0.8916766
  0.6     0.39810717  1.215524  0.8783322  0.9990424
  0.6     0.63095734  1.472457  0.8576833  1.2039381
  0.6     1.00000000  1.884897  0.7967647  1.5547296
  0.6     1.58489319  2.416006  0.6215807  2.0218285
  0.6     2.51188643  2.852162  0.3985127  2.4145440
  0.6     3.98107171  2.900915        NaN  2.4555678
  0.6     6.30957344  2.900915        NaN  2.4555678
  0.6    10.00000000  2.900915        NaN  2.4555678
  0.8     0.01000000  1.044889  0.8735015  0.8562083
  0.8     0.01584893  1.040042  0.8743579  0.8523198
  0.8     0.02511886  1.033350  0.8756643  0.8465936
  0.8     0.03981072  1.024143  0.8778039  0.8372627
  0.8     0.06309573  1.012732  0.8811780  0.8270577
  0.8     0.10000000  1.004796  0.8855772  0.8235556
  0.8     0.15848932  1.036855  0.8858678  0.8581922
  0.8     0.25118864  1.129735  0.8813473  0.9318728
  0.8     0.39810717  1.312509  0.8686677  1.0742903
  0.8     0.63095734  1.649496  0.8268620  1.3529495
  0.8     1.00000000  2.171655  0.6879692  1.8000983
  0.8     1.58489319  2.645776  0.5578926  2.2336370
  0.8     2.51188643  2.900915        NaN  2.4555678
  0.8     3.98107171  2.900915        NaN  2.4555678
  0.8     6.30957344  2.900915        NaN  2.4555678
  0.8    10.00000000  2.900915        NaN  2.4555678
  1.0     0.01000000  1.042889  0.8738610  0.8547933
  1.0     0.01584893  1.037173  0.8748952  0.8500437
  1.0     0.02511886  1.029075  0.8765779  0.8429988
  1.0     0.03981072  1.018856  0.8791001  0.8331726
  1.0     0.06309573  1.004712  0.8834724  0.8210901
  1.0     0.10000000  1.008128  0.8865864  0.8307478
  1.0     0.15848932  1.063315  0.8841498  0.8803295
  1.0     0.25118864  1.181914  0.8770703  0.9729726
  1.0     0.39810717  1.425559  0.8528772  1.1641965
  1.0     0.63095734  1.846403  0.7759609  1.5205852
  1.0     1.00000000  2.371896  0.6053707  1.9812383
  1.0     1.58489319  2.877880  0.3658249  2.4357159
  1.0     2.51188643  2.900915        NaN  2.4555678
  1.0     3.98107171  2.900915        NaN  2.4555678
  1.0     6.30957344  2.900915        NaN  2.4555678
  1.0    10.00000000  2.900915        NaN  2.4555678

RMSE was used to select the optimal model using the smallest value.
The final values used for the model were alpha = 1 and lambda = 0.06309573.
```

When looking at the output, the RMSE associated with alpha = 1 and lambda = 0.06309573 is not the lowest RMSE value.

Comment: You don't want to choose the lowest RMSE as that results in overfitting.  You want the model that has the lowest penalized RMSE.  See if you can get the software to print the penalized RMSE, penalized log-likelihood, or an unbiased estimate of the residual variance, i.e., sum of squared residuals divided by n-p-1 where p is the _effective_ degrees of freedom.  By the way I'd use many more than 3 repeats of CV.

Comment: I understand I optimize for min(RMSE + lambda * coefficients). Apparently, caret then displays only RMSE here, but not the outcome of this overall term?

Comment: Thus, do I understand correctly that I use a cross-validated GLM (via caret or cv.glmnet() ) to find optimal values for alpha and lambda, and then, in a second step, apply these values in my final model? Therefore, I just have to rely on caret that it chooses here the optimal combination of hyperparameters which in total leads to the best fit in the cross-validation (and probably also on the test set)?